# Render router view inside component

Tags: ember.js

Have main template and list of components which represents some items on `index` page. Each component having a link to `show` item route.

How do I render `show` template **inside component**? I don't need to replace all list of components with `show` view, I need just render some item details at the bottom of its own component.

And one more thing. I need to keep url proper. So when I click on item, url should point on this item (eg.: `http://host.com/item/1`). And when I go directly by this link it should render `show` template of element with id=1 inside its own component and keep list of other components on same page (`index` page).

**Update:**

Here is some example code.

Main template (emblem):

```
main.main
  outlet
```

Component:

```
App.GridItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  tagName: 'li'
  classNames: ['grid-item']

  coverUrl: (->
    @get('item.cover_url')
  ).property('item.cover_url')
```

Component template:

```
.grid-item-inner
  = link-to 'items.show' item
    img src=coverUrl
.details
    / <--- Need to render my show view here when link-to 'items.show' clicked
```

Index view:

```
ul.grid
  each item in controller itemController="item"
    grid-item item=item
```

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have thus far?

Comment: @Oren, check for updated question please

Comment: Have you tried putting an {{outlet}} on the index template under the call to create the component? Also, in your description, I assume you mean 'Index template:' and not 'Index view:'.